# What is "intangible cultural heritage"? and why does it have 3 million,700 thousand references on Google?

Tags: meaning

The phrase: "patrimonio cultural inmaterial" has 3,750,000 references. In English this is "intangible cultural heritage".

What does "intangible cultural heritage" mean exactly? In the articles on the subject that I have read, the writing strikes me as quite opaque and stylized; written for specialized readers and thus not particularly helpful.

I checked to see if "Intangible Cultural Heritage" were a buzz-word in academic/government circles in the USA. Turns out it is: this phrase has almost 4 Google million references.

In the papers I have read the concept is NOT related to how a culture creator could generate income. As a member of a cooperative, this aspect is important to the group and me.

Could you explain what "Intangible Cultural Heritage" is supposed to mean? If it is a metaphor, what does the indicated phrase really mean? What is its origin?

Is there anything in "Intangible Cultural Heritage" that could be commercially meaningful or useful to the Mexican artisans like us?

Comment: Maria Alaniz, On the Google search, that is probably showing all websites with **any one** of the keywords. I am surprised that there are **only** 3 million odd pages with "cultural". Academia.org seems tyo troll for subscription on a very broad basis. I have been solicited by them. On the papers, I doubt that many are very relevant to the sort of concerned you have previously raised here. This question is not really about law. I am not sure where, if anywhere, on stack exchange it would fit.

Comment: "On the Google search, that is probably showing all websites with any one of the keywords. I am surprised that there are only 3 million odd pages with "cultural".

Comment: However, The three words are enclosed in quotation marks: thus they are taken as a phrase. I would say that a new article comes out at a rate of one per day on "Patrimonio cultural inmaterial"  (en español) and I have read at least 50 of these papers without comprehension of the underlying meaning of this phrase. This concept is extremely popular: so much has been written about it recently.

Comment: For your Cleveland lawsuit, you ask are *artifacts of intangible heritage the property of their creator?* First, the intangibility aspect makes it hard to prove a definitive case. Then, you have the problems that only colonialists would believe in the *ownership* of heritage, and that borrowing with dignity equals appropriation.

Comment: 1. "the intangibility aspect makes it hard to prove a definitive case" Not in our case.     
 2. "only colonialists would believe in the ownership of heritage" Tend to agree     3.  "borrowing with dignity equals appropriation" Something like that.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it requires the advice of an expert specialist lawyer, which is out of scope for EL&U.

Comment: I do not see how this is related to legal matters. Although migrated from a Law site, law is neither mentioned nor implicit in the question. "Intangible Cultural Heritage" is defined, for one example, in https://ich.unesco.org/en/what-is-intangible-heritage-00003. However, I agree that it is a vague term that is open to many interpretations and nuances. I feel answers will contain too much opinion to be on-topic for this site so I vote, rather regretfully, to close.

Answer (score 6):

[UNESCO's definition](https://ich.unesco.org/en/what-is-intangible-heritage-00003) seems fairly clear. Intangible cultural heritage is that subset of cultural heritage which does not have a tangible, physical aspect. Specific locations, buildings, statues, and products of a culture are tangible cultural heritage, while traditional knowledge and performance are intangible.

A famous tree which is the site of an annual festival in the mythical town of Grumbletwock would be tangible cultural heritage.

The traditional dance performed at the festival each night would be intangible cultural heritage. Both are part of the cultural heritage, it's just that one is a physical location valued by that culture, the other is a practice or knowledge valued by that culture.

The purpose of the term intangible cultural heritage is to emphasize that protecting a culture's heritage involves more than just protecting the physical objects and locations. If you want to preserve the cultural heritage of a group or society, you need to value the knowledge and performances of that society, not just the physical objects it produces.

Answer (score 3):

First they decided to protect the cultural heritage of mankind. There is an UN treaty on this. To protect the heritage that, they had to decide what counts as cultural heritage. Take a [150-year-old mineshaft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zollverein_Coal_Mine_Industrial_Complex) -- scrap iron or a historical monument? When such a site is [endangered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_World_Heritage_in_Danger), there is an outcry, which may or may not help ...

In [2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNESCO_Intangible_Cultural_Heritage_Lists) they decided to protect *intangible* heritage, that is heritage not associated with a specific site. Getting some cultural practice onto the list again helps to raise awareness if it is endangered.

For what you want to do, you need a specialist lawyer.

Comment: I would suggest that, as a craftswoman, your contribution is to the tangible heritage of your cultural group rather than the intangible since craftspeople by definition produce tangible objects. If you are also a poet, songwriter, musician or storyteller you will be contributing to the intangible heritage in that capacity.

Comment: @BoldBen, intanglible in this context means 'not a protected landmark.'

Comment: The physical jewelry we make can be considered "tangible heritage"; still, its cultural content (intangible cultural heritage) is what differentiates our work from that of identical pieces produced by commercial copyists.

Comment: @MariaAlaniz, any one piece of jewelry isn't a museum piece. Your tradition is protected, not the day's work.

Comment: We were  talking about "intangible cultural heritage". My understanding is that this phrase signifies the cultural content of a piece of jewelry.

Comment: @MariaAlaniz, but not the piece itself. It is the traditional craftsmanship that is intangible.

Comment: The KNOWLEDGE of how to craft a traditional piece of jewelry in an authentic way is actually a perfect example of intangible cultural heritage. One of the reasons the term has become so popular recently is that many practices and techniques are being lost. It's always possible to copy the finished product, but there's no way to know every detail of how it was produced just by examining the finished product. This would include things like picking out good versus bad materials, knowing the best way to handle and work the materials, and learning traditional designs and their meanings.

Comment: @ barbecue HACIA UNA VISIÓN HOLÍSTICA DEL PATRIMONIO CULTURAL Manuel DESANTES REAL
"Let us think of all the living expressions inherited from our ancestors and passed on to our descendants, such as, oral traditions, performing arts, social practices, rituals, festive events, processions, observations, practices, ancient and sacred knowledge and techniques related to traditional craftsmanship. This "special" cultural does not have physical entity, they are often referred to as "intangible cultural heritage" or "intangible cultural heritage".

Comment: Free on-line translation makes for odd phrases.

Comment: I think that @o.m. is correct, and this question should be closed as it requires the advice of an expert specialist lawyer, which is out of scope for EL&U.  Thank you, o.m.

Comment: @EllieKesselman, this used to be on Law SE and even Law cannot help.

Comment: Perhaps it is beyond what @o.m. can offer then. Regardless, your answer is good.

Answer (score 3):

From the [*UNESCO Convention for the Safeguarding of the Intangible Cultural Heritage*](https://ich.unesco.org/en/convention) ([text in other languages](https://ich.unesco.org/en/in-other-languages-00102#spanish-authoritative-text))

> For the purposes of this Convention,
>
> 1. The “intangible cultural heritage” means the practices, representations, expressions, knowledge, skills – as well as the instruments, objects, artefacts and cultural spaces associated therewith – that communities, groups and, in some cases, individuals recognize as part of their cultural heritage. This intangible cultural heritage, transmitted from generation to generation, is constantly recreated by communities and groups in response to their environment, their interaction with nature and their history, and provides them with a sense of identity and continuity, thus promoting respect for cultural diversity and human creativity. For the purposes of this Convention, consideration will be given solely to such intangible cultural heritage as is compatible with existing international human rights instruments, as well as with the requirements of mutual respect among communities, groups and individuals, and of sustainable development.
> 2. The “intangible cultural heritage”, as defined in paragraph 1 above, is manifested inter alia in the following domains:
>
> (a) oral traditions and expressions, including language as a vehicle of the intangible cultural heritage;
>
> (b) performing arts;
>
> (c) social practices, rituals and festive events;
>
> (d) knowledge and practices concerning nature and the universe;
>
> (e) traditional craftsmanship.

To summarize, "intangible cultural heritage" (ICH) refers to knowledge, skills, beliefs, and practices that are traditional (passed down between generations within a culture). "Intangible" means it isn't a physical object. So for example clothing that is hundreds of years old might not be ICH, but the skill of making it might be ICH, or a dance involving the clothing might be ICH. The clothing itself might be ICH, but only because it's associated with the dance.

For another example in your field, [Artisanal talavera of Puebla and Tlaxcala (Mexico) and ceramics of Talavera de la Reina and El Puente del Arzobispo (Spain) making process](https://ich.unesco.org/en/decisions/14.COM/10.B.23) is recognized by UNESCO in their "Representative List of the Intangible Cultural Heritage of Humanity".

This doesn't mean that something has to be recognized by UNESCO to be considered ICH. Different organizations may use slightly different definitions of ICH. If you are doing something official like applying for grants that go to preserve ICH, you would need to know the exact definition the group you are working with uses.

Comment: 10. This National (Human Rights) Commission holds that "[c]ultural identity comprises the natural, human, social, historical, spiritual, artistic, economic and political traits, symbols and characteristics that identify a person and a group. It constitutes the cosmovision of peoples, that is, the characteristic that makes them unique and different from other peoples. 
3 In this regard, Cançado Trindade states that "[w]ith respect to members of indigenous communities, cultural identity is closely linked to their ancestral lands.

Answer (score 1):

> why does it have 3 million,700 thousand references on Google?

It does not. On Google.com (the American site) although it says it has in excess of 6.6 million, In fact, it has 189. The number given by Google seems to refer to any combination of any or all of the words in the phrase.

You can show this by going to the bottom of the final page where you will see a message similar to this one:

> *In order to show you the most relevant results, we have omitted some entries very similar to the 189 already displayed. If you like, you can repeat the search with the omitted results included.*

If you do include those results, you still do not reach the mythical number.

Comment: I am going to assume that the down vote is not on the grounds of inaccuracy or lack of citations, but that someone thought it "off-topic". I would suggest (a) it is part of the question (b) directly, but erroneously, informs the first part, (c) These Google numbers are a constant and misleading source that needs correction (d) there is no mechanism for directly informing the OP.